# JAVA: How to search a map?

Tags: java, search, dictionary

I have a Map that has Strings for its keys and sets (that contain integers) for its values

Say my keys look like this "apple", "banana", "orange", etc.

The user enters text and I save it as a String variable. How do I search my map for an identical key?
So if the user types in "apple" how do I give that String to a method and have the method search my map for the "apple" key and return the set of Integers associated with it (values)?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the [Map documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? I got the answer and apparently is not duplicate or vague. Ok, there is a wrong assumption. But aren't we here to correct it?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method

```
 Set<Integer> values = map.get("apple");
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really *search* a Map, you retrieve values from it thus:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Map<String, Set<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    //put new values into map
    myMap.put("MyString", new HashSet<Integer>());
    //get Set from Map
    final Set<Integer> mySet = myMap.get("myString");
}
```

Comment: The answer does relate to the question. It answers the question, but the question is based on a wrong assumption, which we should tackle. Therefore @user2242801 made a better case

Comment: Not sure @DavidZwart, the user says "_I have a Map that has Strings for its keys and sets (that contain integers) for its values_" - so I assume that they have a `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`. I would argure that _user2242801_ made the wrong assumption; not least because they talk about `List`s...

Answer (score 1):

> return the **set of Integers** associated with it (values)?

A map requires the keys to be different, hence I assume that your map declaration would look like `Map<String, List<Integer>> myMap`

To check if a key exists in a Map: 
`myMap.containsKey(key)`
e.g. 
`myMap.containsKey("apple")`

To get the values associated with the key: 
`myMap.get(key)`
 e.g. 
`myMap.get("apple")`

Comment: This has quite a few typos, please correct them. Also, use `back-ticks` to `highlight code`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code example to achieve what you need:

```
public <K, V> Set<K> getKeys(Map<K, V> map, V value) {
    Set<K> keys = new HashSet<>();
    for (Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(value)) {
            keys.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Comment: The Question asks about searching *keys*, not *values*. The [`Map#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method is the solution. The existing [Answer by Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15800623/642706) and [Answer by Boris The Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15800642/642706) are correct and sufficient.